# Creating computed column with circular reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have a table called TaxRates. I want to create a computed column called `EndDate`, of type `DATETIMEOFFSET NULL`.

EndDate should return the value of the StartDate column of the next record in chronological order. If there is no match it should return null.

I don't have a lot of experience with computed columns. This is what i am trying to do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM TaxRates tr
WHERE tr.StartDate > StartDate
ORDER BY StartDate ASC
```

This gives a validation error.

What should I be doing here?

Comment: This is only possible in a computed column via referencing a Scalar UDF that does the required `SELECT`. This solution is very prone to performance problems though. The column can't be marked as `persisted` and it enforces a RBAR nested loop plan to do the lookup. Also it blocks parallelism against that table. [Any reference to a table with a computed column that uses such a function will result in a serial plan, even if the problematic column is not referenced in the query.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx)

Comment: have you considered just using a view?

Comment: Could you make EndDate a real column, and use a trigger to update EndDate on the previous transaction when a new transaction is inserted?

Comment: @mbeckish IMO using a calculated column is more seamless. Storing the enddate just adds more complications.

Comment: @MartinSmith Would a view have the same performance issues as a function?

Comment: No a view wouldn't have the same negative consequences RE parallelism or UDF overhead and that would give you some more options in writing the query that might give a better plan. Though nested loops may well be best anyway. If you are often selecting a large proportion of rows then a self join on `ROW_NUMBER =ROW_NUMBER+1` might be more efficient. SQL Server 2012 has `LAG/LEAD` for this requirement too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if it yields the result you're looking for.

If so we can look in to making this a VIEW.

```
; WITH sorted_taxrates AS (
  SELECT taxbandcode
       , startdate
       , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY taxbandcode ORDER BY startdate ASC) As row_num
  FROM   taxrates
)
SELECT t1.taxbandcode
     , t1.startdate
     , t2.startdate As enddate
FROM   sorted_taxrates As t1
 LEFT
  JOIN sorted_taxrates As t2
    ON t1.taxbandcode = t2.taxbandcode
   AND t2.row_num = t1.row_num + 1
```

Comment: Hmm - there is a problem with this. The next taxrate record will not necessarily be in the next row. There are other columns in the table that are used to distinguish taxrates - I have omitted them for clarity.

Comment: @BlackKnight This is joining based on the order of the `startdate` field. Each row will join to the "next" `startdate`. Are you suggesting that the results aren't correct? If so, please explain how they are incorrect :)

Comment: The "next" taxrate must belong to the same taxband. I would like to be able to do something like this: SELECT startdate
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY startdate ASC) As row_num
  FROM   taxrates WHERE TaxBandCode = [TBC of THIS row] AND Id <> [Id of this row]

Comment: Yep I missed that out because I was still thinking in terms of my UDF solution, where only the StartDate is needed. Will try this out, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using a function, but as pointed out this has performance implications:

My computed column definition:

```
dbo.fn_TaxRates_GetNextStartDate(StartDate)
```

My function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_TaxRates_GetNextStartDate]
(
    @StartDate DATETIMEOFFSET
)
RETURNS DATETIMEOFFSET
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 StartDate FROM dbo.TaxRates tr
            WHERE tr.StartDate > @StartDate
            ORDER BY StartDate ASC)
END
```

Comment: @gvee You are right. Tbh I have only an intermediate knowledge of SQL. MartinSmith's comment went way over my head. However, I understand the issue now. I will start looking for alternatives.

Comment: I've added an answer (which is kind of a comment, but I've posted it that way for ease of formatting, etc)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a working solution. I have also tried to make it clear that it is not the best solution.